# Elixir designer show rendering template failed while I was just clicking the template

Tags: java

[image]

Normally I saw this error only when my jar file in ElixirDesigner's ext file not been updated. But today all of the existing rml templates once I click it will prompt out this error.

Even show the rml template is failed.How come I didn't click render button just to view the template is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because my license is expired and it keeps asking me to install the latest license.
The issue has been solved after I install the latest license.